# Go doing a GET request and building the Querystring

Tags: http, go

I am pretty new to Go and don't quite understand everything as yet. In many of the modern languages Node.js, Angular, jQuery, PHP you can do a GET request with additional query string parameters.

Doing this in Go isn't quite a simple as it seems, and I can't really figure it out as yet. I really don't want to have to concatenate a string for each of the requests I want to do.

Here is the sample script:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular", nil)
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Errored when sending request to the server")
        return
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    resp_body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Println(string(resp_body))
}
```

In this example you can see there is a URL, which requires a GET variable of api_key with your api key as the value. The problem being that this becomes hard coded in the form of:

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=mySuperAwesomeApiKey", nil)
```

Is there a way to build this query string dynamically?? At the moment I will need to assemble the URL prior to this step in order to get a valid response.

Comment: So what is wrong with concatenating a string?

Comment: I suppose nothing, but it's not really a elegant sollution, just thought there is a better way of doing things in Go. 

You see the action changes, the method and then you have to string everything together.

Comment: You can use [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values)'s [`Encode`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Encode) method. You could also use [`URL.String`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.String) to build up the whole URL.

Answer (score 316):

As a commenter mentioned you can get `Values` from `net/url` which has an `Encode` method. You could do something like this (`req.URL.Query()` returns the existing `url.Values`)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    q := req.URL.Query()
    q.Add("api_key", "key_from_environment_or_flag")
    q.Add("another_thing", "foo & bar")
    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

    fmt.Println(req.URL.String())
    // Output:
    // http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?another_thing=foo+%26+bar&api_key=key_from_environment_or_flag
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/L5XCrw9VIG

Comment: Any solution to make the query string parameters in your wanted order? The keys are sorted in `Encode()` method.

Comment: @artificerpi if it was critical for some reason you could reimplement what they do inside the Encode method https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go?s=24222:24253#L845
But I would wonder why it mattered.

Comment: You don't need to use NewRequest if you're not doing anything with it. You can just use `url.Parse("https://something.com/")` instead or even create an URL object directly.

Comment: one thing that is confusing me in this is that it reads like the OP first makes the request, and then after it's finished, goes back and updates the URL. I'm sure that's not the case, so hoping someone can clear up for me why we're first making the API call and then setting the URL we need

Comment: @JakeBoomgaarden the `http.NewRequest` function does not actually call the remote server. It just constructs a `*http.Request` variable for you to use. You can tweak the request to your liking then send it off by passing it to the `*http.Client.Do` method.

Answer (score 61):

Using `NewRequest` just to create an URL is an overkill. Use the `net/url` package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    base, err := url.Parse("http://www.example.com")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Path params
    base.Path += "this will get automatically encoded"

    // Query params
    params := url.Values{}
    params.Add("q", "this will get encoded as well")
    base.RawQuery = params.Encode() 

    fmt.Printf("Encoded URL is %q\n", base.String())
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/YCTvdluws-r

Answer (score 60):

Use `r.URL.Query()` when you appending to existing query, if you are building new set of params use the `url.Values` struct like so

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET","http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // if you appending to existing query this works fine 
    q := req.URL.Query()
    q.Add("api_key", "key_from_environment_or_flag")
    q.Add("another_thing", "foo & bar")

    // or you can create new url.Values struct and encode that like so
    q := url.Values{}
    q.Add("api_key", "key_from_environment_or_flag")
    q.Add("another_thing", "foo & bar")

    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

    fmt.Println(req.URL.String())
    // Output:
    // http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popularanother_thing=foo+%26+bar&api_key=key_from_environment_or_flag
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's work correctly and i have tested this code :

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    url := "https://example.com"

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Api-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXX")//<--add your header

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // print all the response headers
    fmt.Println("Response headers:")
    for k, v := range resp.Header {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k, v)
    }

    fmt.Println("Status:", resp.Status)

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))


}
```

It's like this PHP code :

```
<?php
$curl_h = curl_init('https://example.com');

curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        'Api-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Accept : application/json'
    )
);

# do not output, but store to variable
curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl_h);
echo $response;
```