# Execute a script on local server without ssh

Tags: linux, go, rpc

There is a local area network, machines are in same address space.

I have one manager node which controls other machines. Is there a way to execute a script on any of these machines? (Note: SSH is not enabled and we cannot install any code on these machines except manager machine)

Currently, its done by opening a http session in browser, and then providing username and password, followed by the buttons on the page for each script. I need to automate this in `Go`. Is this possible?

Eg of one such button:

```
`<form ACTION="enableSsh.cgi" method="get">
    <b>
        <input type="SUBMIT" VALUE="Enable SSH Service">
        <input type=hidden name=stamp value="########">
        <input type=hidden name=token value="********">
        <input type=hidden name=frame value="$%$%$%$%">
    </b>
</form>`
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. How do you enable SSH on a machine without access to it? What is the web application? And whats the relation to Go?

Comment: I hope I corrected the mistakes mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Gauranga There's little information there that we can use. We can perhaps guess that your manager machine already can do what you want it to do - but that part is very unclear. If it can already do this, you need to reverse engineer the code you have running on your machines that does this, or ask whoever wrote this code what they have done. If the manager machine already can enable ssh on your other machines, those machines run some non-standard services - It's hard for anyone that does not have access to your machines to figure out how they work.

Comment: ok, let me try if I can get more details. These machines are actually 3rd party machines. And currently, its happening via web. I need to automate that in Golang.

Comment: I guess you may be able to do this. Check in the browser what network traffic - http request-response exchange is happening. You probably may be able to do the same using Go.

Comment: Sure, let me try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, its done by opening a http session in browser, and then providing username and password, followed by the buttons on the page for each script. I need to automate this.

I think you don't need to care about interface at all, until you find a way to execute scripts in backend. From my point of view, it's impossible to execute scripts on the machine without setting up at least SSHD on them. To have your script executed, you need to have some kind of server working on remote machine to handle your requests.

Also, have a look at Configuration Management Systems, such as: [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [SaltStack](https://saltstack.com/), and [so on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software), because even SSH seems to be a too low-level tool for your use-case.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just need a confirmation if its not possible. I tried all possible ways and failed. So, thought of checking once before giving up :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do solely with the Go standard library.

The things to study, in this order:

1. How HTML forms are encoded and sent to HTTP servers by the Internet browsers.

   The things to get familiar with:

   - [The HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) — especially
     its [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) and [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) request methods.
   - [Forms in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) — especially pt. 13 "Form submission".
2. When a HTML form is submitted, the data sent to the HTTP server
   is typically encoded in one of two forms:

   - The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding
     is used to make [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) requests and
   - The `multipart/form-data` encoding is used to make [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
     requests.

   In your example, the form has the `method="get"`
   attribute which indicates the form submission uses [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)
   and hence the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding for its
   data.
3. The `net/http` package in the Go standard library which can be used to
   make HTTP requests.

With all this things in place, you need to make a HTTP [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)
request to a proper server and URL, with a proper set of parameters.

The server is the same from which you get that HTML page.
The URL will be `/enableSsh.cgi`.

Now you just need to make up the request and to it.

Here is [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30657518/720999)
but really googling for `golang+get+query+with+parameters` will bring
you myriads of similar examples.
The query parameters are those form fields—`stamp`, `token` and `frame`,
and their values are, well, what is about to be submitted.

---

In the case you'll need to `POST` a form with the `multipart/form-data`
encoding, you'd use
the `mime/multipart` package in the Go standard library, whose
`Writer` type can be used to build a stream of data encoded according
to the `multipart/form-data` rules.