# Issue HTTP GET with form values in Go

Tags: http, go

I see there is an easy way to send a post with form values, but is there a function I could use to do essentially the same as [PostForm](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm) but for a GET request?

-- edit --

Basically, I want to construct the URL: https://uri.com?key=value
but without using string concatenation with unescaped keys and values.

Comment: Do you want to send the form as the request body (which is usually ignored by a server for GET requests) or do you send the form as query parameters?

Comment: @ThunderCat As query paramaters

Comment: @EatonEmmerich Note that that is not called a Form or anything related to a post, you just want to construct a query string. See of [Go doing a GET request and building the Querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652577/go-doing-a-get-request-and-building-the-querystring)

Comment: @nos does a form imply the data is in the body?

Answer (score 1):

Encode the query parameters using [Values.Encode](https://godoc.org/net/url#Values.Encode). Concatenate the base URL and query parameters to get the actual URL.

```
resp, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%s?%s", baseURL, data.Encode()))
```

Comment: thanks, The net/url Values was the missing link! Also, this one is shorter than the duplicate answers

Answer (score -1):

As explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/), you probably don't actually want to do this. Most servers won't do anything useful with a form body in a `GET` request—and most that do will just treat it as synonymous with the same parameters sent in a query string, in which case you should just put them in the query string of your `url.URL` object in the first place.

However, if you do have a good reason to do this, you can. As the docs you linked explain, `PostForm` is just a thin convenience wrapper around [`NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) and [`Do`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do). Just as you're expected to use `NewRequest` yourself if you want to add custom headers, you can use it to attach a body.

And if you look at [the source to `PostForm`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=25182:25264#L763), it's pretty trivial:

```
return c.Post(url, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", strings.NewReader(data.Encode()))
```

Basically, instead of this:

```
resp, err := client.PostForm(url, data)
```

… you do this:

```
body := strings.NewReader(data.Encode())
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, body)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```