# dynamically build url query string without URL encoding

Tags: http, go, url, urlencode

How can I add a query parameter which is a timestamp in RFC3339 without URL encoding? This question is an extension of [Go doing a GET request and building the Querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652577/go-doing-a-get-request-and-building-the-querystring)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular", nil)
    t := time.Now()

    q := req.URL.Query()
    q.Add("api_key", "key_from_environment_or_flag")
    q.Add("another_thing", "foo & bar")
    q.Add("timestamp", t.Format(time.RFC3339))
    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339))
    fmt.Println(req.URL.String())
    // Output:
    // 2009-11-10T23:00:00Z
    // http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?another_thing=foo+%26+bar&api_key=key_from_environment_or_flag&timestamp=2009-11-10T23%3A00%3A00Z
}
```

I want

`http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?another_thing=foo+%26+bar&api_key=key_from_environment_or_flag&timestamp=2009-11-10T23:00:00Z`

https://play.golang.org/p/2rg-qXZNx2a

Thank you

Comment: The question is why do you want the URL without encoding? Any URL parser will interpret your URL as it having `timestamp=2009-11-10T23:00:00Z`.

Comment: @icza the api I am accessing apparently does not interpret the URL correctly

Comment: `req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode() + t.Format("&timestamp="+time.RFC3339)`

Comment: I have the same problem, is your API an OData API by chance ? Because yes, the "dollar" sign is encoded to "%24" and the API is unable to understand it... In that case it is *RSA Archer*