# How te send a POST with both URL parameters and a JSON body?

Tags: http, go, post, url-parameters, document-body

I found how to send a `POST` with URL parameters, or how to send a `POST` with a JSON body, but I do not know how to combine them together (a request with both a URL with parameters, and a JSON body).

The code below (which is not correct) shows the commbination I am looking for. I can use either `bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr)` or `strings.NewReader(parm.Encode())` but not both.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var jsonStr = []byte(`{"title":"my request"}`)
    parm := url.Values{}
    parm.Add("token", "hello")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://postman-echo.com/post", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr), strings.NewReader(parm.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

}
```

How to build a full `POST` call with all the components?

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to send the URL parameters in the request body. As you say, you can't use both (because an HTTP request is meant to have a single body, the URL is separate).

Comment: Those aren't URL parameters. URL parameters, by definition, are parameters _to the URL_.

Comment: @Flimzy yes I know, I am starting with Go and trying to port what I know from Python where a single call gets both the parameters and the body.

Comment: Curious. If you know that, I wonder why you said otherwise in your question.

Comment: @Flimzy: can you please point where so that I can correct the misunderstanding?

Comment: "I found how to send a POST with URL parameters" -- Yet you aren't sending any URL parameters. You're sending a body--which by definition is _not_ URL parameters.  URl parameters are _part of the URL_, which you claim to know.  Yet, you send them as the body??

Comment: @Flimzy: yes, my mistake was coming from looking at calls such as `req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://...", strings.NewReader(parm.Encode()))`. In Python (requests) it is a single call that uses both the URL parameters and the body in one single call. I did not realize that in Go this was a two-step operation (new request, update of the URL parameters, and then the actual call  (with the body)). As for "which I claim to know" - well I guess not having English as a first language does not help with the subtleties of the language. I should have mentioned that I know that **in general**

Comment: You can do the same in Go, too: `http.NewRequest("POST", "https://.../?url_parameters_go_here_IN_THE_URL", someBody)`

Comment: By passing `strings.NewReader(param.Encode())` as a body argument, it **is not URL parameters**.

Comment: @Flimzy: I prefer however using the mechanisms of the language to ensure proper encoding etc., rather than manually chaining the parameters

Comment: Nobody said you have to manually chain parameters.  All I said is _they need to go in the URL_. How you build that URL is entirley up to you. Nothing you pass as body argument will ever be in the URL.

Comment: @Flimzy *" ... is not URL parameters"* ahhhh, ok. I was reading a page where `parm` was used for both the body and the URL (in different examples) - this is where I got it wrong.

Comment: I'm glad we finally cut through the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the only json as your request body, and apply the URL parameters like this:

```golang
req.URL.RawQuery = parm.Encode()
```

From [Go doing a GET request and building the Querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30657518/11424673)